# Python re.findall returning links with unwanted string afterwards

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall, scraper

I have a python script using BeautifulSoup to scrape.  This is my code:

```
re.findall('stream:\/\/.+', link)
```

Which is designed to find links like:

```
stream://987cds9c8ujru56236te2ys28u99u2s
```

But it also returns strings like this:

```
stream://987cds9c8ujru56236te2ys28u99u2s  [SD] Spanish - (9.15am)
```

i.e. with spaces and extra stuff which I don't want.  How can I express the

```
re.findall
```

So it only returns the link first part?

(Thanks in advance)

Comment: `$` is the regex for end of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non-greedy match (adding `?` to the pattern) with a word boundary character `'\b'`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'stream:\/\/.+?\b', link)
['stream://987cds9c8ujru56236te2ys28u99u2s']
```

Or if you want to match only word characters you can simply use `'\w+'`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'stream:\/\/\w+', link)
['stream://987cds9c8ujru56236te2ys28u99u2s']
```

Comment: Thanks for this help but unfortunately the string in the link isn't a word - it can consist of letters and numbers so word boundaries or word characters don't work.  I'm going to try with $ suggestions above as the boundary for the end of the string.  The non-greedy suggestion helps though.

Comment: @manners I said *if*, never said it's going to work in all cases. Also, you mean the first approach does not work?